# Can I see or browse raw segment.com events on Keen.io?

Tags: keen-io, segment-io

Isn't there a way to list raw events from segment.com, with all their attributes, on Keen.io?

It seems the UI only allows me to create aggregations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [extractions](https://keen.io/docs/api/#extractions). These will give you the raw data from whatever source they were given to. Keep in mind however, that the performance of an extraction will generally be slower than any other kind of query. Furthermore, doing too many of them can cause irate Keen engineers* to get on your case.

*In this case, probably me.

Comment: I see. It's just that sometimes people are developing applications and they want to confirm whether their events are arriving with the right structure. Moreover, there are cases where someone needs to query events that they don't know yet. Hence, being able to see some raw samples would help users to create queries.

Comment: Absolutely @GabrielBR. That's why it is supported in the first place.  It isn't a great thing to do constantly as your primary use case, but there are definitely valid reasons for doing it.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I thought to myself "Oh, I hope I don't put too much load on the service." Then I saw "Results are limited to 10 million events." I think I'm in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to log into your Keen account and go to the Explorer. Click `preview collections` to pull up a schema inspector tool and sample events.

[image]
[image]

You can also run an `extraction` query in the explorer or any of the query SDKS. You can also easily download a CSV of your raw events.[image]

[Data Explorer Guide](https://keen.io/docs/compute/data-explorer-guide/) has more tips & tricks as well.